# React + GraphQL + Apollo + Mongo - CRUD on big objects with subforms

Tags: reactjs, graphql, crud, apollo

I'm working on an administration and I'm looking for the best architecture.

Let's say we have one big object (for example website), which has some basic data (name, title, etc.) and then also holds some collections of objects (pages) with their data. I can fetch this object with GraphQL with all of the subcollections.

My idea is to load this object in EditWebsite component and then have some tabs with subforms (one tab for basic settings of the website, another one for basic settings of the pages). In each subform, I can edit some part of the object and then I will have one submit button to submit all forms (basically send a new version of the object to the server).

I can also have some live preview there, which will get the actual version of the object and I can in whatever subform edit the object and see immediately the changes.

Is this a good approach? I know, that maybe it will be better to submit just the parts, which were changed (this can be implemented later).

Thanks for your opinions :)